# How to redirect Saxon 9-4ee schema validation messages to file using cmd interface only?

Tags: java, batch-file, saxon

I'm using a batch script to process multiple XML files. As part of the process I run Saxon 9.4 enterprise validator. This works fine and I can use %ERRORLEVEL% to determine success or error. In case of an error validation messages are printed on screen.

The problem is that when I try to redirect the validation messages to a log file, the logfile is always empty and the messages still appear on screen instead of the log file. I have tried two methods so far and can't think of anything else to try. I have no java programming experience and cannot write my own stream handler.

This is what I've tried so far but no success:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set CLASSPATH=%CD%\system\saxon9ee;%CD%\system\saxon9ee\saxon9ee.jar;%CD%\system\saxon9ee\resolver.jar

java.exe com.saxonica.Validate ^
   -x:org.apache.xml.resolver.tools.ResolvingXMLReader ^
   -y:org.apache.xml.resolver.tools.ResolvingXMLReader ^
   -r:org.apache.xml.resolver.tools.CatalogResolver ^
   --StandardErrorOutputFile:error.txt "input.xml"
```

Above creates a log file but it's always empty. I presume validation errors are not classed as 'error' internally. 
I have also tried various combinations of [command redirection operators](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) but no luck either

```
java.exe com.saxonica.Validate ^
   -x:org.apache.xml.resolver.tools.ResolvingXMLReader ^
   -y:org.apache.xml.resolver.tools.ResolvingXMLReader ^
   -r:org.apache.xml.resolver.tools.CatalogResolver input.xml >> validation.log 2>&1
```

Is there another way to catch validation messages when running java saxon from the command line/batch script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't immediately see why setting --StandardErrorOutputFile doesn't work, but many operating system shells also support something like

```
2>error.txt
```

for redirecting the standard error output. It may vary though from one shell language to another.